# NameError: name 'clean_up_bubs' is not defined even though it is?

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anush/Documents/Python Stuff/Bubble Blaster 2.py", line 56, in <module>
    clean_up_bubs()
NameError: name 'clean_up_bubs' is not defined
```

MAIN GAME LOOP:

```
while True:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    clean_up_bubs()
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
    def get_coords(id_num):
        pos = c.coords(id_num)
        x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
        y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
        return x, y
    def del_bubble(i):
        del bub_r[i]
        del bub_speed[i]
        c.delete(bub_id[i])
        del_bub_id[i]
    def clean_up_bubs():
        for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1 , -1):
            x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
            if x < -GAP:
                del_bubble(i)
```

Comment: Heres the Defined thing:

Comment: def clean_up_bubs():
        for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1 , -1):
            x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
            if x < -GAP:
                del_bubble(i)

Comment: but it keeps on saying I haven't defined it

Comment: why are you declaring functions is a while loop? That makes no sense at all

Comment: I fixed the other Error but the Game Works then this happens and the game freezes

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anush/Documents/Python Stuff/Bubble Blaster 2 fix.py", line 70, in <module>
    clean_up_bubs()
  File "C:/Users/anush/Documents/Python Stuff/Bubble Blaster 2 fix.py", line 65, in clean_up_bubs
    del_bubble(i)
  File "C:/Users/anush/Documents/Python Stuff/Bubble Blaster 2 fix.py", line 60, in del_bubble
    del_bub_id[i]
NameError: name 'del_bub_id' is not defined

Comment: of course it does `del_bub_id` is not defined anywhere, I think you need to look at a basic tutorial http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: are you sure it should  not be `del bub_id[i]`?

Comment: I am using carol vordermans book but it is confusing and the code is supposed to work like I done it

Comment: oh yeah it should be del bub_id... but I got the 'clean_up_bubs is not defined error again -_-'

Comment: I don't know what to do :(

Comment: You're calling it before you define it in the first loop.

Comment: Yeah, But my book says to do the way as it is so what should I do ?

Comment: You should return that book, or use it as a coaster.

Comment: Please keep in mind what was said earlier in the comments: This code is a mess. Please use a good tutorial.

Comment: Cool Thanks Everyone Who Helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `clean_up_bubs()` before you define it in the first loop. Move the function definitions out of and above the `while` loop.

```
def get_coords(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y


def del_bubble(i):
    del bub_r[i]
    del bub_speed[i]
    c.delete(bub_id[i])
    del_bub_id[i]


def clean_up_bubs():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1 , -1):
        x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
        if x < -GAP:
            del_bubble(i)


while True:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    clean_up_bubs()
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Now I got this error :( Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anush/Documents/Python Stuff/Bubble Blaster 2 fix.py", line 54, in <module>
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
NameError: name 'BUB_CHANCE' is not defined , You can tell I'm bad at python

Comment: What is `BUB_CHANCE` supposed to be?

Comment: Its the Bubble Generator

Comment: I meant what's its value. It should be an `int`.

Comment: I think perhaps you should close that book and find a good tutorial :).